# How to create Synchronous Function Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have created a swf project with flex and i have some checkboxes on it and whenever the checkbox seleced it will call the checkbox handler:

```
function checkBoxHandler() {
   //call resultHandling
   var obj:myObjectType = new myObjectType();
   resultHandling(obj)
}

function resultHandling(myObject:myObjectType) {
   //implementation code to send a request to server side
}
```

is it possible to make the "resultHandling(...)" to be a synchronized function? So there will be a que whenever we make a call to that function especially when there are multiple function calls

Answer (score 2):

As Flex is Flash the limitations to Flash apply to Flex too. One of these is (Actually in newer Flash versions this no longer is 100% valid) that Flash has only one thread. This thread does everything from updating/drawing the ui, processing the application logic, handling IO, etc. Therefore a synchronous call would be a blocking call and in Client-Server communication this block can be quite long. Therefore Flash doesn't support blocking calls to a server and you won't be able to find a solution for this ... unfortunately.

But be assured, actually you will start creating more robust applications this way. I have noticed creating more and more asynchronous solutions even in places I could use synchronous calls :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can create an arraycollection and store all your myObjectType objects in it. Then do something like-

```
   var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(); 
   function checkBoxHandler() {
   //call resultHandling
   var obj:myObjectType = new myObjectType();
   arr.addItem(obj);
   }

   function resultHandling(myObject:myObjectType) {
   //implementation code to send a request to server side
   }

   function webServiceResponseHandler(){
   //receive the response from server
   sendWSRequest();
   }

   function sendWSRequest(){
       if(arr.length > 0)
       {
           resultHandling(arr.getItemAt(0));
           arr.removeItemAt(0);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most Flash I/O is asynchronous and there is no way to change that. Consider using inline nested handlers

```
function checkBoxHandler() {
    var obj:myObjectType = new myObjectType();

    var resultHandling:Function = function():void {
        //you can just reference obj here

        var resultHandling2:Function = function():void {
        };
    };

    //implementation code to send a request to server side
}
```

or use a task scheduler such as the [Parsley Command Framework](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/3.0/manual/commands.php).

Comment: Inline and anonymous functions are generally discouraged in Flash. Unless they are used and disposed of properly, they can be a major memory leak.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case if you are not using them as event handlers, e.g. passing into a `Responder`.